# Traces on a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. In Takesaki's book, the trace $\tau$ on $M$ is defined as follows:

> $\tau$ is a function defined on the positive cone $M_{+}$ with values in $[0, +\infty]$   satisfying some conditions.

My question: Can we define $\tau$ on $M$?

When we define a tracial state $\phi$ on a $C^*$–algebra $A$, the domain of $\phi$ is $A$, rather than $A^+$.

Comment: The definition of a trace depends on the author's intentions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the second square bracket in $[0,\infty]$. What Takesaki is defining is a *tracial weight*. Many von Neumann algebras have no tracial states, but do have faithful semifinite tracial weights. These precisely those with no type III central summand, and where the identity is infinite (i.e., they have at least a component of type I$_\infty$ of II$_\infty$).

The typical example is the trace on $B(H)$ with $H$ infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks! But why the domain of the trace is the positive cone of $M$, rather than the whole $M$.

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense. Take two infinite projections, $p,q\in B(H)$. What is the trace of $p-q$?

Comment: B(H) has no tracial state. In  a $C^*$-algebra $A$, the dommain of the tracial state is the whole $A$, rather than $A^+$.

Comment: Indeed, $B(H)$ has no tracial state when $H$ is infinite-dimensional, but it always has a faithful tracial weight. Looks like you didn't read my answer.

Comment: Thanks! But how to construct faithful tracial state on $B(H)$ when $H$ is infinite dimensional. Or more generally, how to construct a faithful tracial weight on $M$, where $M$ is a VNA such that has no type III central summand and the identity is infinite.?

Comment: On $B(H)$, it's **the** trace. So you have a faithful tracial weight on all type I factors. On II$_1$ factors, it's canonical how to construct the unique faithful tracial state from comparison of projections. Any type II$_\infty$ factor is $N\otimes B(H)$, so you can construct a faithful normal tracial weight by $\tau\otimes\operatorname{Tr}$, where $\tau$ is the unique trace on $N$. For an arbitrary von Neumann algebra with no type III central summand, write it as a direct integral of factors, and form the tracial weight by integrating the corresponding tracial weights.